# MD5 hash of byte array in powershell with same result as in bash

Tags: bash, powershell, hash, md5

I have the following bash command which will calculate the MD5 hash of a byte array:

```bash
test=$(printf \\x86\\x78\\x45\\xe9\\x7c\\x4e\\x29\\xdc\\xe5\\x22\\xb9\\xa7\\xd3\\xa3\\xe0\\x7b\\x15\\x2b\\xff\\xad\\xdd\\xbe\\xd7\\xf5\\xff\\xd8\\x42\\xe9\\x89\\x5a\\xd1\\xe4)
test2=$(echo -n "$test" | md5sum | cut -c-32)
```

"test2" will return the value `becff4d09fd02fd6dfc89fbd3bc0af2b`

Now I want to this in PowerShell with the same result. By doing this with an byte array as well with a string as shown in the bash command I got different results. Does anyone knows, how to get the right result?

Comment: Add your code to your question (no comment here).

Comment: For more info, see: [mcve]

Comment: Add the Powershell version too.

Comment: `(Get-FileHash -InputStream ([System.IO.MemoryStream] ([byte[]] @(0x86,0x78,0x45,0xe9,0x7c,0x4e,0x29,0xdc,0xe5,0x22,0xb9,0xa7,0xd3,0xa3,0xe0,0x7b,0x15,0x2b,0xff,0xad,0xdd,0xbe,0xd7,0xf5,0xff,0xd8,0x42,0xe9,0x89,0x5a,0xd1,0xe4))) -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower()`. Figuring out what the individual parts do is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Alternatively `[BitConverter]::ToString([Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create().ComputeHash(@(0x86,0x78,0x45,0xe9,0x7c,0x4e,0x29,0xdc,0xe5,0x22,0xb9,0xa7,0xd3,0xa3,0xe0,0x7b,0x15,0x2b,0xff,0xad,0xdd,0xbe,0xd7,0xf5,0xff,0xd8,0x42,0xe9,0x89,0x5a,0xd1,0xe4))).Replace('-','').ToLower()` should do too...